# Https Issues With Yii Module

Tags: ssl, module, https, apache2, yii

I have a module up and running in Yii.  I can access the module at `http://url/module` without any problems.  I can not get a secure connection to work, however.

The primary site works fine when I attempt to connect with https (`https://url`).  When I attempt to access anything within my module I get

```
Not Found

The requested URL /module was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu) Server at url Port 443
```

I haven't been able to find any leads searching here or on Google.  Any help would be great.

**EDITED**
Based on ldg's suggestion I updated the ssl config file.  Details for Ubuntu 11.04 follow.

/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl

Change

```
...
< Directory /var/www/ >
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
< /Directory >
...
```

To

```
...
< Directory /var/www/ >
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
< /Directory >
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the ssl config file for Apache and look to see if it has an entry for "AllowOverride". If it's set to "None", change to "All" (or however you have it set for non-ssl).

Do all the URLs work on your primary site in ssl?

Comment: Nope. Only the home page. Looking into the ssl config now.

Comment: Took a little time to track down the ssl config, but that did it. Thanks!